Как сделать чтобы персонаж не прилипал к "стене" в Unity
Сделал управление через rigidbody, если разогнавшись прыгнуть в стену и продолжать идти в неё то персонаж не падает, а прилипает к стене
float moveSpeed = 4f;

float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed; ;
 float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
 rb.linearVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(horizontal,rb.linearVelocity.y, vertical));


Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа

Можно сослаться на фичу из Skyrim =)
А если по существу, то тут не в управлении проблема,а в коллайдерах.
Так же, если скорость вашего персонажа очень высокая, может происходить подобное.
